# Skipping rows when double white space pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My textfile raw data looks like this:

```
 ID   x1    x2
 1    4.3   4.7
 2          3.2
 3    3     5.6
 4          2.1
```

There are double spaces in the text file where there is no x1.

Then when reading into pandas using:

```
 df = pd.read_csv(filename,delim_whitespace=True)
 #or trying
 df = pd.read_csv(thia_concat,  sep = "\s+")
```

creates a data frame like this:

```
 ID   x1    x2
 1    4.3   4.7
 2    3.2   nan
 3    3     5.6
 4    2.1   nan
```

I can't figure out how to tell pandas what to do with the double space to assign the value to x2 and not x1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might want to try StackOverflow for this question...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table) or [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) without passing a separator/delimeter and let Pandas figure it out:

> "Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine this"

```
df = pd.read_table(filename)
df

     ID   x1    x2
0   1    4.3   4.7
1   2          3.2
2   3    3     5.6
3   4          2.1


df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df

     ID   x1    x2
0   1    4.3   4.7
1   2          3.2
2   3    3     5.6
3   4          2.1
```